# Neo4j Interactive graph freezes

Tags: performance, debugging, encryption, neo4j

We have been using Neo4j for quite some time without any problem. Recently, the community version we are using started to be very buggy. So buggy that we cannot use the Interactive graph view. I would note that we did not make any change to our project and that we had this issue about one year ago. How was the issue solved? It was not. It just started working again after some time. Yesterday, I had a colleague launch the tool in Linux/Google Chrome. It worked perfectly.

Another colleague launched the tool in windows and it was as buggy as my windows instance. I would add that our computers are sufficiently powerful to handle our use case.

Any idea how we could solve this puzzle?

| OS Windows 10 |
Google Chrome Version 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Neo4j Browser version: 3.2.18
Neo4j Server version: 3.5.4 (community)

Github issue raised here:https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues/1066

Comment: Can you create a new issue on the [browser github](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues) with additional context and details (including your OS and browser versions)? That's probably the best place to start. Aside from the freezing (possibly also a slowdown for display?) are you noting any other issues?

Comment: Slowness is the only issue. I created a new issue in Github 4 days ago, still hoping for an answer soon.